# How to get up and running with spaCy for Vietnamese?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I success with English

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

python -m spacy download en
```

I read https://spacy.io/models/xx . How to use with Vietnamese use `xx`?

Answer (score 0):

Call Python terminal from Anaconda Navigator.

```
python -m spacy download xx_sent_ud_sm
```

or

```
python -m spacy download xx_ent_wiki_sm
```

test

```py
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("xx_sent_ud_sm")
doc = nlp("Hôm nay trời nắng to")
displacy.serve(doc, style="dep")
```

or

```py
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("xx_ent_wiki_sm")
doc = nlp("Hôm nay trời nắng to")
displacy.serve(doc, style="ent")
```

result
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjTqJ.png